# yii mutliple joins not showing all columns

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have the following createcommand:

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('q.*, qcia.value, qcim.value')
    ->from('quotas q')
    ->leftjoin('quota_company_item_activations qcia', 'qcia.quota_id = q.id')
    ->leftjoin('quota_company_item_mrcs qcim', 'qcim.quota_id = q.id')
    ->where('q.id=:id', array(':id' => $quota_id))
    ->queryRow();
```

In the result array i should have twice a value field, but the array looks like that:

```
[id] => 3
[name] => September Sales Quotas
[company_id] => 1
[user_id] => 22
[datestart] => 2014-09-01
[dateend] => 2014-09-30
[created] => 2014-09-30 21:12:44
[modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[value] => 60.00
```

Why it only retrieves one value (from last leftjoin) ?

Comment: You need to use an alias for one of the values.. php arrays are indexed by the keys.. the first value was overwritten by the second value

Comment: @Manquer You should make that an answer, possibly with an example of what the `select` should look like.

Comment: like: select('q.*, qcia.value avalue, qcim.value mvalue') ?

Comment: @Manquer: please post it as answer so that i can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an alias for one of the values.. php arrays are indexed by the keys.. the first value was overwritten by the second value 
with something like this

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('q.*, qcia.value avalue, qcim.value mvalue') 
    ->from('quotas q')
    ->leftjoin('quota_company_item_activations qcia', 'qcia.quota_id = q.id')
    ->leftjoin('quota_company_item_mrcs qcim', 'qcim.quota_id = q.id')
    ->where('q.id=:id', array(':id' => $quota_id))
    ->queryRow();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was used from CakePHP that breaks it down in subarrays for the joined tables. Totally "blind" to not see yii is not doing it like that.

Comment: yii will also do that for ActiveRecord queries and objects i.e. queries on your model classes however in this case we are using the underlying CDbCommand they just return an arrays or CDbDataReader, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the alias so you can get different `value` columns.

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('q.*, qcia.value AS qcia_value, qcim.value AS qcim_value')
->from('quotas q')
->leftjoin('quota_company_item_activations qcia', 'qcia.quota_id = q.id')
->leftjoin('quota_company_item_mrcs qcim', 'qcim.quota_id = q.id')
->where('q.id=:id', array(':id' => $quota_id))
->queryRow();

var_dump($query);
```